# Why is Linux policy-based routing (PBR) not working for ping?

Tags: networking, routing, ping, iproute2, policy-routing

First of all, it seems as if this question is about Linux, but it seems to me that it is about basic routing concepts.

I happen to have the following configuration:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to ensure symmetric routing on the server (CentOS 7), so that incoming and outgoing traffic from it takes the same path for any pair of nodes (using both network interfaces).

Suppose I set the static IP address `192.168.0.210/24` for `eno1` and `192.168.1.210/24` for `eno2` (`eno1` and `eno2` is the same as `eth0` and `eth1` in other Linux distributions).

Then I created 2 routing tables (one for each network interface) in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
...
101     net1
102     net2
```

Then I created routes in each routing table and policy routing rules to direct outbound traffic to the appropriate routing table, as follows:

```
$ ip route show table net1
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 scope link

$ ip route show table net2
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 scope link

$ ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local 
101:    from 192.168.0.0/24 lookup net1 
102:    from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup net2 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

These are the first tests I did (which worked as expected):

```
$ ip route get 192.168.100.100 from 192.168.0.210
192.168.100.100 from 192.168.0.210 via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1
    cache

$ ip route get 192.168.100.100 from 192.168.1.210
192.168.100.100 from 192.168.1.210 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2
    cache

$ ip route get 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.100 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 src 192.168.1.210
    cache
```

Finally, using the `tshark` tool I started monitoring the network interfaces `eno1` and `eno2` and made requests through each, for example:

```
$ curl --interface eno1 https://google.com
$ curl --interface eno2 https://google.com
$ traceroute -i eno1 google.com
$ traceroute -i eno2 google.com
$ ping -I eno1 -c 2 google.com
$ ping -I eno2 -c 2 google.com
```

The first 4 commands worked as expected (incoming and outgoing traffic was properly captured by `tshark` on each network interface), but the `ping` commands did not. This is the output from `tshark` for the `ping` commands:

[image]

As you can see, the `ping` worked only for `eno2`. After trial and error, I realized that the `ping` only worked for the network interface that was associated with the generic default gateway:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eno2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
```

From my understanding, the `ping` commands should have worked even without setting a generic default gateway, since the default gateways set in `net1` and `net2` should have been used, is this correct?

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with the way `ping` works? Why did the first 4 commands work?

Comment: Does eno1 have any other IP addresses assigned to it? Can you show complete output of `ip a l`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between [*binding to an interface*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/socket.7#SO_BINDTODEVICE) and *binding to an IP address*. While the 2 working cases do bind to an interface, they avoid the problem that `ping` encounters (to be explained later). Let's start with fixing `ping`. I reproduced OP's setup to help giving illustrations.

The route lookup when *only* binding to an interface is not:

> ```
> ip route get  from 192.168.1.210
> ```

but:

```
# ip route get oif eno2 to 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.100 dev eno2 src 192.168.1.210 uid 0 
    cache
```

The tables 101 and 102 are not involved here, since there is no local source address specified in the lookup. Moreover, there is no default route in the main routing table for 192.168.100.100. But as the interface was forced to `eno2`, such default route is automatically created... **without gateway**. The visible symptom is that there will be ARP requests emitted from 192.168.1.210 to 192.168.100.100 since the bogus route tells 192.168.100.100 is directly reachable.

Had OP also added the (usually useless) additional default route with higher metric, such as:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 metric 101
```

then:

```
# ip route get oif eno2 to 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.100 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 src 192.168.1.210 uid 0 
    cache
```

Now, since there was already a matching default route through `eno2` it is selected, with a correct gateway. `ping` would now work. Routing table 102 is still not involved.

### Routing rule selector for bound interface

The actual correct way to have the route defined in table 102 to be used is to use the [`oif`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-rule.8#oif) selector in ip rules:

> `oif` *NAME*
>
> select the outgoing device to match. The outgoing interface is only
> available for packets originating **from local sockets that are bound to
> a device**.

Let's use it (and delete the 2nd default route to show it's not needed anymore):

```
ip route delete default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 metric 101
```

```
ip rule add oif eno1 lookup 101
ip rule add oif eno2 lookup 102
```

The lookup now will match and become:

```
# ip route get oif eno2 to 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.100 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 table 102 src 192.168.1.210 uid 0 
    cache
```

This time, as the selector matched, the correct routing table was used, with a default defined with a gateway.

That's what had to be done.

Note: `ping` also accepts binding to an IP address (`ping -I 192.168.1.210 -c 2 google.com`) or even both (`ping -I eno2 -I 192.168.1.210 -c 2 google.com`). These case would have worked without additional routing rules as explained.

---

### Why did the two first cases work anyway?

(Remove the correction above and...)

As was seen in previous faulty route resolution:

> ```
> # ip route get oif eno2 to 192.168.100.100
> 192.168.100.100 dev eno2 src 192.168.1.210 uid 0 
>     cache
> ```

the correct IP source address still gets selected. As soon as TCP has to emit a packet, its route lookup will be presented with the source address 192.168.1.210. This case *does match* the selector in rule pref 102:

```
# ip route get from 192.168.1.210 oif eno2 to 192.168.100.100
192.168.100.100 from 192.168.1.210 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 table 102 uid 0 
    cache
```

Table 102 still got selected by rule pref 102. Once the adequate table is selected, no matter why it was selected, correct routing happens.

For UDP it's a bit more complicated, because it depends if the UDP client uses [`connect(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/connect.2) which then behaves like previous TCP case: a source address will be used, or chooses to not use `connect(2)`. For example this command would fail to be routed correctly without the missing routing rules, because it doesn't use `connect(2`) and the routing stack will be queried without source (ie: with INADDR_ANY = 0.0.0.0):

```
echo test | socat udp4-datagram:203.0.113.1:8888,so-bindtodevice=eno2 -
```

while this one would succeed because it uses `connect(2)`:

```
echo test | socat          udp4:203.0.113.1:8888,so-bindtodevice=eno2 -
```

Of course both will work fine once the two missing routing rules are added.

One can check that traceroute does use `connect` by using `strace`:

```
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eno2\0", 5) = 0
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33434), sin_addr=inet_addr("203.0.113.1")}, 28) = 0
...
```

Comment: Hello, A.B.
Thank you very much for your reply.
I have not been able to get the time out to test it, but since you were the only one to respond and the answer sounds like it is correct, I will give you the bounty.
I will accept the answer when I can test it later.
Congratulations on your 10k. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I tried everything you suggested and `ping` still didn't work, you can see the result in [this image](https://ibb.co/p09LR0x) (I even tried to `ping` bound to an IP address and it didn't work either). Either way, I think you offer a simpler way to apply PBR, as well as other valuable information, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: In your screenshot there are missing rules: `101:    from 192.168.0.0/24 lookup net1 ` and 
`102:    from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup net2 ` and also missing default routes in tables net1 (`default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 `) and net2 (`default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 `): all that you had in your question doesn't appear in the screenshot. They must be kept. You can update (with text, not screenshot!) the question if this doesn't work. Just be sure to keep all that was present in the initial question, and add what I added in my answer.